# pytorch can't resolve and autocomplete in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, pytorch, pylint

[here is what happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qpau.png)

I install the extension called Visual Studio Intellicode and pylint to autocomplete the code, but when

```
import torch
import numpy
```

It says unresolved import 'torch', and vscode didn't autocomplete the code of torch's modules like nn, but the code(e.g nn.Conv2d) can still work and get the right output. And the error only appears when import torch, numpy and pandas is alright.